# Editing a string (char array) copying to input string (scanf or fgets.. gets) possible?

Tags: c, string, char, edit, scanf

I have a question for you, is it possible to the the following in C?
I mean:

In the code I would have something like

```
char example[] = "Single"
```

then do edit this string, I would copy to input of `scanf`,
and then I could just use backspace to delete the last char 'e', 
then I would press enter, and `scanf` would store the new example string
on the same pointer example..

Possible in C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to interactively edit string on your terminal. Functions from `stdio.h` don't offer such functionality. They only read and write data.

You can use libraries such as [readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) or [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `example` as a place to store data.  Think of this as a constant.

Instead you can say

```
char example[7] = "Single";
```

Now you can change those 6 characters if you like but anything bigger will be a problem.

Comment: Yes ok, thanks for your reply, I know that mate, was just an example.
I know that I can edit a string by just using scanf and then store it where I want.
But, for example, if I want to add only a dot to a string, I would like to edit string on scanf and then store it.
scanf would show me the actual string and I would have the option to edit it, do u undestand?
Thanks alot mate!